# NorthscaleClient does not Set values consistently

Tags: .net, memcached, distributed-caching

I am using `NorthscaleClient` from [Enyim Memcached](http://memcached.enyim.com/) client libary to store objects in [Northscale Memcached Server](http://info.northscale.com/Memcached.html). Below does not work consistently, assertion fails most of the time. Am I doing anything wrong?

```
        // File size is 360kb
        var reader = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\RHDSetup.log");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Assert.True(new NorthScaleClient(c).Store(StoreMode.Set, i.ToString(),
                                reader));

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the usage of `new NorthScaleClient(c).Store(StoreMode.Set, i.ToString(),
                                reader)` inside `Assert.True` method. After removing inline call and initializing it outside works well. I guess, it is probably sometimes the object goes out of scope and assertion fails.